# Could not load main class from .java class file

Tags: java, python, gephi

I'm using Python to visualize a graph through a tool named wot using jupyter notebook. It utilizes Gephi, a java-based graph utility. I try to run function to return coordinate output files as below:

```
run_gephi(input_graph_file, output_coord_file, n_steps):
    layout = 'fa'
    import psutil
    memory = int(0.5 * psutil.virtual_memory()[0] * 1e-9)
classpath = os.path.dirname(
    pkg_resources.resource_filename('wot', 'commands/resources/graph_layout/GraphLayout.class')) + ':' + \
            pkg_resources.resource_filename('wot', 'commands/resources/graph_layout/gephi-toolkit-0.9.2-all.jar')
subprocess.check_call(['java', '-Djava.awt.headless=true', '-Xmx{memory}g'.format(memory=memory), '-cp', classpath, \
                       'GraphLayout', input_graph_file, output_coord_file, layout, str(n_steps), str(os.cpu_count())])
```

Then it returns following error in my jupyter notebook:

```
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-5fc832689b87> in <module>
----> 1 df, adata = compute_force_layout(ds)

<ipython-input-7-6cb84b9e0fa0> in compute_force_layout(ds, n_neighbors, n_comps, neighbors_diff, n_steps)
 24                 writer.write("{u} {v} {w:.6g}\n".format(u=i + 1, v=j + 1, w=W[i, j]))
 25 
---> 26     run_gephi(input_graph_file, output_coord_file, n_steps)
 27     # replace numbers with cids
 28     df = pd.read_table(output_coord_file, header=0, index_col='id')

<ipython-input-16-28772d0d10cc> in run_gephi(input_graph_file, output_coord_file, n_steps)
  7                 pkg_resources.resource_filename('wot', 'commands/resources/graph_layout/gephi-toolkit-0.9.2-all.jar')
  8     subprocess.check_call(['java', '-Djava.awt.headless=true', '-Xmx{memory}g'.format(memory=memory), '-cp', classpath, \
----> 9                            'GraphLayout', input_graph_file, output_coord_file, layout, str(n_steps), str(os.cpu_count())])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
339         if cmd is None:
340             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 341         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
342     return 0
343 

CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-Djava.awt.headless=true', '-Xmx25g', '-cp', '/home/iik/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wot/commands/resources/graph_layout:/home/iik/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wot/commands/resources/graph_layout/gephi-toolkit-0.9.2-all.jar', 'GraphLayout', '/tmp/gephiznxedn32.net', '/tmp/coordsd64x05ww.txt', 'fa', '10000', '8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

and following message was found in terminal

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class GraphLayout
```

I can found "GraphLayout.java" and "gephi-toolkit-0.9.2-all.jar" files in the path, so I really don't know why it can't be loaded.
Do you have any suggestions?

- Add *

The class GraphLayout is not contained in Gephi but defined by GraphLayout.java.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the "GraphLayout" class is not in the root of the jarfile `gephi-toolkit-0.9.2-all.jar`. It's likely in a package, so you need to specify the exact "path" to the class (represented by folders in the jar file), e.g. `org.gephy.somepackage.GraphLayout`.

Comment: Ignatiamus is almost certainly correct.  You can look at the contents of the Jar file with the `jar` command (from the Java JDK) `jar tf <jarfile>`.  You can also just give the Jar file a .zip extension and look at it with an ordinary Zip file viewer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I missed an information causing your confusion. The class GraphLayout is not included in gephi jar but defined by GraphLayout.java. Gephi jar file contains the other classes to define GraphLayout class.

Comment: Problem solved. The class file was corrupted. Download the class file again solved problem.